# Importing function from another module: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute

Tags: python, class

I am making a battle like program where there is one module that contains functions to create the character classes and one where the main code is. When I import a function to change the health of one of the characters I get an error saying:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute
```

Here is the function:

```
def changeHealth(self,health,defense,Oattack):
    self.health = health - (Oattack - defense) - 15
    return self.health
```

and when I call the function on the main code module I do this:

```
import CharacterClass 
CharacterClass.changeHealth(self,health,defense,Oattack)
```

Comment: `self = Character()` this should be removed- you don't do this in Python.

Comment: There are many problems with your approach. You are redefining functions within one class definition and creating variables that you aren't using (`self = Character()` creates a class variable that you never access).Try changing your data model. You could create the main character and opponent as `Characters` in the program (not inside the class). Then have a `battle` function that accesses the attributes of the main character and opponent and changes the health of each one as appropriate.

Comment: @Craig , how would I create my opponent? Is my code on the right track other than the self = Character()

Comment: @Josh.W you have a good start, but there are some problems with the way you are structuring the Character class. I've put together a minimal Class that demonstrates how you could structure the object. Let me know if the answer that I posted helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how you could create a class for `Character` that could be used for any character in your program. Each class should represent a unique type of object, in this case a "character". Each character should be an instance of that class. You then handle the interaction between character instances with either functions or class methods.

```
class Character(object):
    def __init__(self, name, attack, defense, health):
        self.name = name
        self.attack = attack
        self.defense = defense
        self.health = health

    def injure(self, damage):
        self.health = self.health - damage

    def __str__(self):
        return "Character: {}, A:{}, D:{}, H:{}".format(self.name, self.attack, self.defense, self.health)

    def check(self):
        print("this works")

    def doAttack(self, other=None):
        dmg = self.attack - other.defense
        if dmg > 0: 
            other.injure(dmg)
            print("{} caused {} damage to {}".format(self.name, dmg, other.name))
        else:
            print("{} did not injure {}".format(self.name, other.name))


hero = Character('Hero', 8, 10, 20)
opponent = Character('Monster', 4, 5, 10)


opponent.doAttack(hero)
print(hero)
print(opponent)
print()

hero.doAttack(opponent)
print(hero)
print(opponent)
print()
```

Running this code produces:

> ```
> Monster did not injure Hero
> Character: Hero, A:8, D:10, H:20
> Character: Monster, A:4, D:5, H:10
>
> Hero caused 3 damage to Monster
> Character: Hero, A:8, D:10, H:20
> Character: Monster, A:4, D:5, H:7
> ```

This is a pretty basic example. You may want to read through [Object Oriented Programming in Python](http://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Object_Oriented_Programming.html) (or a similar text) to learn the concepts behind structuring object-oriented code.

Comment: Sorry, @Craig Stack Overflow wouldn't let me add another question because apparently, I've asked too many in the past 2 days while I've only asked 1... I had to edit the question to my new question so your answer may not make sense. Feel free to delete it if you want